# Search for node in unorganized binary tree?

Tags: binary-tree

This is a conceptual question. I have a tree where the data is stored with strings but not stored alphabetically. How do I search through the entire tree to find the node with string I'm looking for. So far I can only search through one side of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

1. You may iterate throught all tree levels and on each of level check all nodes. Depth of the tree is equivalent to numbers of itetations.
2. You may recursively go down to each branches and stop all itetations when node is found (by using external variable or flag) or if there is no child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the thing you can:

```
       1. traverse the tree in any manner, say `DFS` or `BFS`
       2. while travering nodes, keep checking the the current node is equivalent to the key string you are searching for.
       2.1. compare each character of your search string with each character of current node's value.
       2.2. if match found, process your result.
       2.3. if not, continue with point 2. 
       3. if all the nodes exhausted, you don't have any match. stop the algorithm.
```

The complexity of above mentioned algorithm will be:

```
       O(N)* O(M) => O(NM)
       N - nodes of your tree.
       M - length of your node's value + length of your search key's value.
```